# difference between Keepsynced(true) and a Firebase Listener ? do we need to set Keepsynced to False when activity destroyed?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to develop a small app. I read that `KeepSynced(true)` will keep an empty listener on a location. I would like to know if it is difference from a Listener Event (ValueEvent, ChildEvent...) or not. Do we need to set Keepsynce to False when activity destroyed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keepSynced is no different than any other listener.  You just don't provide a callback, and you don't know when the data at that location is synchronized.

> Do we need to set Keepsynce to False when activity destroyed?

That's up to you.  You should stop synchronizing the data when you no longer want that to happen.  It's not necessarily related to your activity lifecycle.